# Regex to match unique characters NOT in a set

Tags: regex

I'd like to match unique characters that are NOT "ymd"

example 1 :

`mm-dd-yyyy`     should match only 1 character `-`

example 2 :

`d. m. y.`       should match only 1 `.` character and 1 whitespace character

I've tried negative lookahead using this pattern

`/([^ymd]+\b)(?!.*\1\b)/`

which works, but the match for the example 2 is `". "`

Ideally, I'd like it to find 2 single character matches :  `"."` and 1 whitespace character

Comment: Did you try [`([^ymd])(?!.*?\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/t6BXde/1) ?

Comment: Maybe instead just use replace ymd + distinct? e.g in c# var chars = new Regex("[ymd]").Replace("yy. mm. dd", "").Distinct()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, simply match single characters. Be sure to put them in a group. This will make all non-ymd characters match individually:

```
([^ymd])
```

Then, use a negative lookahead. This will make only the **last** unique character match:

```
(?!.*\1)
```

Full solution:

```
([^ymd])(?!.*\1)
```

[See it live!](https://regex101.com/r/htcTIz/2)

Comment: Doesn't work if order changes or char is doubled, e.g. "yyyy .mm. dd"
"yyyy..mm. dd"

Comment: @Vitaly thanks for your feedback! I noticed it and edited the answer about 3 minutes ago.

Comment: @Marc Note that the `(?!.*\1)` makes the regex engine match the *last* occurrence of the char captured. If you need the *first* one you'd need a variable width lookbehind, and that depends on what regex library you are using.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  But if it's the same char, why would I care if it's the first or last ?

Comment: @Marc position matters if you're intending on doing some transformation on the original text, rather than just listing the matches to input in some other algorithm. That's why I bolded the "last" on my answer.

Comment: But if you don't care about that, you're right: It doesn't matter.